# nodejs socket.io express handshake error

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I try to create a real time app by socket.io.
Server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');

var app = express()
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , io = io.listen(server);

app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.redirect('/login')
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3001);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client connected...');
    socket.on('send_login_data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
    socket.on('connect_failed', function(){
        console.log('Connection Failed');
    });
    socket.on('connecting', function () {
        console.log('connecting...');
    });

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('connected!');
    });
```

I caught the next error:

> GET http://localhost:3001/socket.io/1/?t=1447539302809 404 (Not Found)

As I understand, it's a handshake error. 
How can I fix it?

Thanx.

Comment: Does a regular http request to `http://localhost:3001` work?

Comment: @jfriend00, sure, express return login form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, make absolutely sure there are no errors showing anywhere in case some module isn't installed properly.

Then, make sure you have the same version number of socket.io on client and server and that you have the server-side version installed on the server.

Then, I've seen folks have issue with this before, even when following the instructions on the socket.io web site and it's never been clear exactly what was wrong with that sequence.  But, what I know is that this sequence will work:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3001);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

See related issues: [Where is my client side socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491737/where-is-my-client-side-socket-io/32492775#32492775) and [Node + Socket.io Connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320907/node-socket-io-connection-issue/26320962#26320962)

---

I don't know if this is causing the issue or not, but you are attempting to redefine the `io` variable when it has already been declared in this:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = express()
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , io = io.listen(server);
```

The second reference to `io = io.listen(server)` is essentially this:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = io.listen(server);
```

Which is not correct Javascript.  Again, may not be causing your issue, but it is not technically proper Javascript.

Comment: I use your working example without 'http' module and it started work. I assume 'http' module was overcoding. Thank you!